# creating network of n(n taken from user) nodes in omnet++

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

I am working on a project for Location privacy by using OMNET++,
 Recently i have developed a network of two nodes (like Tic- Toc game) and want to convert it into a real network which vary from 2 to n  nodes as per user requirement.

This is structure of 2 nodes:

```
simple Txc1
{
gates:
input in;
output out;
}
`enter code here`// Two instances (tic and toc) of Txc1 connected both ways.
// Tic and toc will pass messages to one another.
//
network Tictoc1
{
submodules:
tic: Txc1;
toc: Txc1;
connections:
tic.out --> { delay = 100ms; } --> toc.in;
tic.in <-- { delay = 100ms; } <-- toc.out;
}
```

How can i do that for n nodes??
I mean how can I input n(from user) in OMNET++??

Anyone please...

Comment: You did not specify what topology you need? Full graph or a random graph? Without that only a generic answer is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest to take a look at the 'neddemo' example in the samples folder. It shows how to set up parametrized topologies. The exact answer is obviously depends on the topology you actually need (but the demo has several typical ones).

To ask a user interactivaly you should specify something like this in the INI file:

MyNetwork.numberofnodes = ask

that will show a dialog for the user when the simulation started.